R summarise by group, then build avg. based on condition
I have to create a table that shows average values of each variable DT06_1-DT06_19 (caution: I only have variables DT06_1-DT06_3, DT06_7, DT06_10-DT06_19.
The averages shall be computed by group. I have four groups shown in insuff_suff_res_cat (caution: not every participant shows values for each of the four categories. I dont have rows where the participant shows values for a category).
And last, the averages on each DT06-variable shall only be computed where the respective DT01-variable shows the value "1" instead of "0".
So together: For each group of the variable "insuff_suff_res_cat", please calculate the average value of each DT06-variable (e.g., for DT06_1, for DT06_2 and so on) only if the respective DT01-variable == "1".
my dataset:
structure(list(ID = c("poHYvL", "34HEg4", "poHYvL", "34HEg4", 
"Y0FPVt", "uXaA9j", "nIogJg", "9tAGOE", "Y0FPVt", "uXaA9j", 
"nIogJg", "9tAGOE"), insuff_suff_res_cat = c("not_enough_resources", 
"not_enough_resources", "not_enough_resources_help", "not_enough_resources_help", 
"enough_resources", "enough_resources", "enough_resources", "enough_resources", 
"enough_resources_help", "enough_resources_help", "enough_resources_help", 
"enough_resources_help"), DT01_1 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), label = "Printed textbooks:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_2 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), label = "Digital textbooks:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_3 = structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), label = "Photocopied materials:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_4 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), label = "Academic articles and other articles/blogs:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_5 = structure(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), label = "Lecturer slides/lecturer notes/lecture recordings:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_6 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), label = "Notes from lectures (your notes or other students’ notes):Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_7 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), label = "Printed practice test questions or exam practice papers:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_8 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), label = "Practice test questions or exam practice papers on my VLE or LMS (e g , Moodle, Canvas, Blackboard):Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_9 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), label = "University VLE or LMS discussion forums:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_10 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), label = "Digital study / revision platforms / websites or apps (could include flashcards, test questions, multiple choice questions, content summaries etc):Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_11 = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), label = "Video (e g , Youtube, TED talks or similar platforms):Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_12 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Social Media (e g , TikTok):Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_13 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), label = "Online chat forums:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_14 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), label = "Chat-GPT or other AI based chatbots (/or open-AI technologies):Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_15 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), label = "Study plan apps/ goal tracking apps:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_16 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Memory booster / distraction blocker apps:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_17 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Software development platforms / Data analysis software:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_18 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), label = "Tutoring services:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT01_19 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Other:Tool / resource usage", format.spss = "F5.0", labels = c(Unchecked = 0, 
Checked = 1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), DT06_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "150", NA, NA, NA, "170", NA, 
NA, NA), DT06_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", NA, "40", NA, "0", NA, 
"40", NA), DT06_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", NA, NA, NA, "0", NA, 
NA, NA), DT06_7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", "0", NA, NA, "0", "0", 
NA, NA), DT06_10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", "0", NA, NA, "0", "0", 
NA, NA), DT06_11 = c(NA, "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", NA, "60", "0", 
"0", NA, "45"), DT06_12 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    DT06_13 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", NA, NA, NA, "0", NA, NA, 
    NA), DT06_14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "50", "0", NA, NA, "50", 
    "0", NA, NA), DT06_15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "21", 
    NA, NA, NA, "21"), DT06_16 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), DT06_17 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), DT06_18 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "60", NA, NA, NA, "60", NA), DT06_19 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")

the desired outcome (numbers are invented):

I have already tried to apply the summarize command but I really can't find a solution to connect it to my conditions. Any help appreciated.

Please provide reproducible example of your dataset. You can use dput(...).

Looks like you have provided your dataset, but it doesn't seem to be complete. For example, from your dataset I can only see 3 distinct groups: not_enough_resources,
not_enough_resources_help, and enough_resources. but your question indicates there should be 4.

And also please provide your expected output based on your test input.

Thank you all and excuses! I have replaced the reproducible example now. The desired output is indicated in the picture. Any help appreciated.

Using haven, dplyr, and tidyr, here is the workflow to return mean values of insuff_suff_res_cat groups from DT06* columns based on pairwise relationships with DT01* columns:

As the DT06 column suffixes are not consecutive like the DT01 columns, create vector of DT06 suffixes to filter result
Convert all DT* columns to as.numeric() so they can be interpreted by R and pivoted together
Pivot long with all DT01* values in one column and all DT06* values in another column. DT* column suffixes stored in new ID1 column
Filter so only DT01 == "1" remain
Summarise DT06 column by groups defined by insuff_suff_res_cat and ID1
Pivot insuff_suff_res_cat column to wide format
Add any missing DT06 suffixes that may not have been included in the summarise result e.g. DT06_12, DT06_17, and DT06_19 in this example
Filter so only DT06* suffixes remain
Change ID1 values back their original values

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(haven)

# Create vector of DT06 suffix values e.g. c(1,2,3,7,10,...) for filtering result
DT06_cols <- sub("^DT06_", "", grep("^DT06", names(df), value = TRUE))

result <- df |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("DT"), as.numeric)) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("DT"),
               names_to = c(".value", "ID1"),
               names_pattern = "(DT\\d+)_(\\d+)") |>
  filter(DT01 == 1) |>
  summarise(DT06 = round(mean(DT06, na.rm = TRUE), 2),
            .by = c(insuff_suff_res_cat, ID1)) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID1,
              names_from = insuff_suff_res_cat,
              values_from = DT06) |>
  complete(ID1 = DT06_cols) |>
  arrange(as.integer(ID1)) |>
  filter(ID1 %in% DT06_cols) |>
  mutate(ID1 = paste0("DT06_", sprintf("%02d", as.integer(ID1))))



data.frame(result)
#        ID1 not_enough_resources not_enough_resources_help enough_resources enough_resources_help
# 1  DT06_01                   NA                        NA              150                   170
# 2  DT06_02                   NA                       NaN               20                    20
# 3  DT06_03                   NA                       NaN                0                     0
# 4  DT06_07                   NA                        NA                0                     0
# 5  DT06_10                   NA                        NA                0                     0
# 6  DT06_11                    0                         0               20                    15
# 7  DT06_12                   NA                        NA               NA                    NA
# 8  DT06_13                   NA                        NA                0                     0
# 9  DT06_14                   NA                        NA               25                    25
# 10 DT06_15                   NA                        NA               21                    21
# 11 DT06_16                   NA                        NA               NA                    NA
# 12 DT06_17                   NA                        NA               NA                    NA
# 13 DT06_18                   NA                        NA               60                    60
# 14 DT06_19                   NA                        NA               NA                    NA


@L Tyrone, many thanks! It is almost perfect. Still I need the (DT01_1 =="1") to be changed according to each DT06-variable like: For each group of the variable "insuff_suff_res_cat", please calculate the average value of each DT06-variable (e.g., DT06_3) only if the RESPECTIVE DT01-variable (e.g., DT01_3) == "1"

Another minor point is that the convertion to numeric does not work for my cols. The DT06-variables are all character and the DT01-variables are all "unknown". I can convert them when using the ineconomic function df$DT06_1 <- as.numeric(df$DT06) for each DT06 and for each DT01-variable, but it won't convert with your line of code.

@L Tyrone - Wow it seems to work! (I've updated my data already, so no problems anymore). Don't know how you did that but awesome, many many thanks! If you can quickly explain how the names pattern line "(DT\d+)_(\d+)") works that would be fantastic.

@NadineM. - Glad it worked for you. The “(DT\d+)(\d+)” regular expression (regex) works like this. It has two capture groups, which are defined by the brackets “()”. The first capture group looks for a literal match of “DT” and one or more numbers after “DT” using “\d+”. “\d” looks for numbers, and as “\” is a special character, it needs to be ‘escaped’. The “+” means one or more. The “ “ is a literal match that separates the two capture groups. Finally, like the first capture group, the second capture group uses “\d+”  looks for one or more numbers.

@L Tyrone, thank you so much for the updates and clarifications, and many excuses for the confusion
